A limit involving $n$ and $k(n)$ such that $k(n) \to \infty$ and $n-k(n) \to \infty$
Consider
$$\left(1+\frac{p_n}{q_n} v\right)^{k-1} \left(1-\frac{p_n}{1-q_n} v\right)^{n-k}$$
where $k$ is a sequence in $n$ such that $k(n) \to \infty$, $n-k(n) \to \infty$, $v \in \mathbb{R}$ and
$$p_n^2 = k(n-k)n^{-3}$$
$$q_n = \frac{k}{n}$$
I want to prove that as $n \to \infty$, $(1+\frac{p_n}{q_n} v)^{k-1} (1-\frac{p_n}{1-q_n} v)^{n-k} \to \exp(-\frac{1}{2}v^2)$.
Plugging in the definition of $p_n$ and $q_n$, I obtain
$$\left(1+\left(\frac{n-k}{nk}\right)^{0.5}v\right)^{k-1} \left(1- \left(\frac{k}{n(n-k)}\right)^{0.5}v\right)^{n-k}$$
but I do not see why this sequence would converge to $\exp(-\frac{1}{2}v^2)$.
The reference for this Statistics of Extremes by Segers.



The image has a $q_n$ and a $\bar q_n$ . What is the difference ?

$\bar{q_n} = 1-q_n$ @lenobloy

Sketch.
Let $A =\left(\frac{n-k}{nk}\right)^{1/2}v$ and $B= \left(\frac{k}{n(n-k)}\right)^{1/2}v $.  We have that $A \to 0$, $B \to 0$. Further,  $k A = (n-k) B = k^{1/2} (1-k/n)^{1/2} v  \sim  k^{1/2}  $
We have
$$ \log \left[(1 +A)^{k-1}(1 -B)^{n-k} \right]  = (k-1) (A - \frac12 A^2 + O(A^3)) - (n-k) ( B + \frac12 B^2 + O(B^3)) 
$$
The leading terms here cancel, so we need to be a little careful. But doing the math, that simplifies to
$$ - \frac12 v^2 + o(1)$$

do $kA \to 0$ also?

No. It behaves as $k^{1/2}$
